# *.svb files stored in Git as binary. How to store they as plain text?

Tags: git, vbscript, testcomplete

We wrote our tests using Testcomplete and VB script. Extension of TC files is *.svb.

```
diff --git a/Script/libSystem.svb b/Script/libSystem.svb
index c183d4d..94e81dd 100644
--- a/Script/libSystem.svb
+++ b/Script/libSystem.svb
Binary files differ
```

When we try to view SVB files using Gerrit it only offer to download it (not show them). And another problem that Gerrit don't let to make review for such files. Every time we need to download files and compare they locally.

How to fix it?

We try to add file .gitattributes that contains '*.svb -crlf -diff' to the folder with *.svb files, but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

quoting [gitattributes man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html)

> The simplest way to mark a file as binary is to unset the diff attribute in the .gitattributes file:
>
> *.ps -diff
>
> This will cause git to generate **Binary files differ** (or a binary patch, if binary patches are enabled) instead of a regular diff.

In that case you actually want the "diff" attribute set (+diff), not unset (-diff)